# How to use a tsvector field to perform ranking in Django with postgresql full-text search?

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

**I need to perform a ranking query using postgresql full-text search feature and Django with `django.contrib.postgres` module.**

According to [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchrank), it is quite easy to do this using the `SearchRank` class by doing the following:

```
>>> from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchRank, SearchVector
>>> vector = SearchVector('body_text')
>>> query = SearchQuery('cheese')
>>> Entry.objects.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, query)).order_by('-rank')
```

This probably works well but this is not exactly what I want since **I have a field in my table which already contains tsvectorized data that I would like to use** (instead of recomputing tsvector at each search query).

Unforunately, **I can't figure out how to provide this tsvector field to the `SearchRank` class instead of a `SearchVector` object on a raw data field**.

Is anyone able to indicate how to deal with this?

**Edit**:
Of course, simply trying to instantiate a `SearchVector` from the tsvector field does not work and fails with this error (approximately since I translated it from french):

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ERROR:  function to_tsvector(tsvector) does not exist

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your model has a [`SearchVectorField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvectorfield) like so:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVectorField

class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    search_vector = SearchVectorField()
```

you would use the [`F expression`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import F

...
Entry.objects.annotate(
    rank=SearchRank(F('search_vector'), query)
).order_by('-rank')
```

Comment: I did not know the [Query Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#query-expressions)... Thanks for the answer, it works perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible to add a `weight` to the vector? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#weighting-queries

Comment: When you update the field, add the weights there: `SearchVector("your_field", weight='A', config='english') + SearchVector("your_other_field", weight='B', config='english')`

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeing mixed answers here on SO and in the official documentation. `F Expressions` [aren't used in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) for this. However it may just be that the documentation doesn't actually provide an example for using SearchRank with a SearchVectorField.

Looking at the output of `.explain(analyze=True)` :

Without the F Expression:

```
Sort Key: (ts_rank(to_tsvector(COALESCE((search_vector)::text, ''::text))
```

When the F Expression is used:

```
Sort Key: (ts_rank(search_vector, ...)
```

In my experience, it seems the only difference between using an F Expression and the field name in quotes is that using the F Expression returns much faster, but is sometimes less accurate - depending on how you structure the query - it can be useful to enforce it with a `COALESCE` in some cases. In my case it's about a 3-5x speedboost to use the F Expression with my `SearchVectorField`.

Ensuring your SearchQuery has a `config` kwarg also improves things dramatically.